# SwiftUI displaying a Decimal value does not update after a state change

Tags: swift, swiftui

I was re-implementing the macOS calculator App in SwiftUI as an exercice and stumble on an issue where a view does not updates following a state change. Unfortunately, I was not able to trim down the code to a minimal reproductible example so here is the whole code.

The idea is to represent the calculator state with a state machine, which I implemented as an enum with payloads:

```swift
/// State machine representing the calculator state. Handling of the "." key is not yet implemented.
enum CalculatorStateMachine {
    /// The irst number is being typed.
    case left(lhs: Decimal)
    
    /// An operator is selected.
    case op(lhs: Decimal, op: String)
    
    /// The second number is being typed.
    case right(lhs: Decimal, op: String, rhs: Decimal)
    
    /// The "=" button is taped and the result displayed.
    case result(value: Decimal)
    
    static var initial: CalculatorStateMachine {
        .left(lhs: 0)
    }
    
    /// Computes the result of `op(lhs, rhs)` where `op` represents a binary function of type `(Decimal, Decimal) -> Decimal`.
    func compute(_ lhs: Decimal, _ op: String, _ rhs: Decimal) -> Decimal {
        switch op {
        case "+": return lhs + rhs
        case "-": return lhs - rhs
        case "x": return lhs * rhs
        case "/": return lhs / rhs
        default: fatalError("Unknown operator '\(op)'")
        }
    }
    
    /// Implements the transition between state.
    /// - Parameter key: The event that triggered the state transition.
    mutating func transitionForKey(_ key: String) {
        precondition(Key.validKeys.contains(key), "Invalid key '\(key)'")
        
        switch self {
        case .left(let lhs):
            switch key {
            case "0"..."9", ".":
                if let newValue = Decimal(string: lhs.description + key) {
                    self = .left(lhs: newValue)
                }
            case "+", "-", "x", "/":
                self = .op(lhs: lhs, op: key)
            case "%":
                self = .left(lhs: lhs / 100)
            case "±":
                self = .left(lhs: -lhs)
            case "AC", "C":
                self = .left(lhs: 0)
            default:
                return
            }
        case .op(let lhs, let op):
        switch key {
            case "0"..."9", ".":
            if let newValue = Decimal(string: key) {
                    self = .right(lhs: lhs, op: op, rhs: newValue)
                }
            case "+", "-", "x", "/":
                self = .op(lhs: lhs, op: key)
            case "%":
                self = .op(lhs: lhs / 100, op: op)
            case "±":
                self = .op(lhs: -lhs, op: op)
            case "=":
                self = .result(value: compute(lhs, op, lhs))
            case "C":
                self = .left(lhs: lhs)
            case "AC":
                self = .left(lhs: 0)
            default:
                return
            }
        case .right(let lhs, let op, let rhs):
            switch key {
            case "0"..."9", ".":
                if let newValue = Decimal(string: rhs.description + key) {
                    self = .right(lhs: lhs, op: op, rhs: newValue)
                }
            case "+", "-", "x", "/":
                // TODO: Implement operation priority
                self = .op(lhs: compute(lhs, op, rhs), op: key)
            case "%":
                self = .right(lhs: lhs, op: op, rhs: rhs / 100)
            case "±":
                self = .right(lhs: lhs, op: op, rhs: -rhs)
            case "=":
                self = .result(value: compute(lhs, op, rhs))
            case "C":
                self = .right(lhs: lhs, op: op, rhs: 0)
            case "AC":
                self = .left(lhs: 0)
            default:
                return
            }
        case .result(let value):
            switch key {
            case "0"..."9", ".":
                if let newValue = Decimal(string: key) {
                    self = .left(lhs: newValue)
                }
            case "+", "-", "x", "/":
                self = .op(lhs: value, op: key)
            case "%":
                self = .left(lhs: value / 100)
            case "±":
                self = .left(lhs: -value)
            // TODO: case "=" should reapeat the previous operation
            case "C", "AC":  // TODO: "C" and "AC" have different behaviors
                self = .left(lhs: 0)
            default:
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is four states and a method to transition between states in response to pressed keys (digits, operators, ...) which are represented by `String` (the `key` parameter).

I then embedded this model into an `ObservedObject` (the view model) by publish the changes in state:

```swift
final class CalculatorController: ObservableObject {
    @Published var state: CalculatorStateMachine = .initial

    func keyPressed(_ key: String) {
        state.transitionForKey(key)
    }
}
```

The UI has three components. First, the keys of the calculator (digits, operators, ...) are modeled with the `Key` view. The `value` property represents the key while the `calculator` is the observed view model injected in the environment used to transmit key press actions:

```swift
struct Key: View {
    let value: String
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var calculator: CalculatorController
    
    init(_ value: String) {
        precondition(Key.validKeys.contains(value), "Invalid key \(value)")
        self.value = value
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            calculator.keyPressed(value)
        } label: {
            ZStack {
                color
                Text(value)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .monospacedDigit()
                
                switch calculator.state {
                case .op(lhs: _, op: let op), .right(lhs: _, op: let op, rhs: _):
                    if op == value {
                        Rectangle().strokeBorder(lineWidth: 2)
                    }
                default:
                    Color.clear
                }
            }
        }
        .buttonStyle(.plain)
    }
    
    var color: Color {
        switch value {
        case "AC", "C", "±", "%":
            return Color(red: 100/255, green: 100/255, blue: 100/255)
        case "/", "x", "+", "-", "=":
            return Color(red: 244/255, green: 158/255, blue: 63/255)
        case "0"..."9", ".":
            return Color(red: 125/255, green: 125/255, blue: 125/255)
        default:
            fatalError("Unknown key '\(value)'")
        }
    }
}

extension Key {
    static let validKeys = Set([
        "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
        "+", "-", "x", "/", ".", "±", "%", "AC", "C", "=",
    ])
}
```

The second view it the `ResultView` which is responsible of displaying the operations. Its only property is `result` which is the decimal number to display.

```swift
struct ResultView: View {
    let result: Decimal
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(red: 83/255, green: 83/255, blue: 83/255)

            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text(result.description)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .monospacedDigit()
                    .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the third view is the calculator UI which shows the keys and the display. It owns he calculator view model and inject it in the child view hierarchy. It defines one specific method `displayedValue` which retrieves the number to show on the display:

```swift
struct CalculatorView: View {
    @StateObject private var calculator = CalculatorController()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 1) {
            ResultView(result: displayedValue)
//            Text(displayedValue.description)
            
            HStack(spacing: 1) {
                Key(shouldShowAC ? "AC" : "C")
                Key("±")
                Key("%")
                Key("/")
            }
            HStack(spacing: 1) {
                Key("7")
                Key("8")
                Key("9")
                Key("x")
            }
            HStack(spacing: 1) {
                Key("4")
                Key("5")
                Key("6")
                Key("-")
            }
            HStack(spacing: 1) {
                Key("1")
                Key("2")
                Key("3")
                Key("+")
            }
            HStack(spacing: 1) {
                HStack(spacing: 1) {
                    Key("0")
                }
                HStack(spacing: 1) {
                    Key(".")
                    Key("=")
                }
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(calculator)
    }
    
    var displayedValue: Decimal {
        switch calculator.state {
        case .left(lhs: let lhs), .op(lhs: let lhs, op: _):
            return lhs
        case .right(lhs: _, op: _, rhs: let rhs):
            return rhs
        case .result(let result):
            return result
        }
    }
    
    var shouldShowAC: Bool {
        switch calculator.state {
        case .left(lhs: let v) where v == .zero,
             .right(lhs: _, op: _, rhs: let v) where v == .zero:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

To finish, Here is the main entry point of the program:

```swift
@main
struct CalculatorApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            CalculatorView()
                .frame(width: 80*4, height: 70*6)
        }
    }
}
```

---

This program works well if we ignore some stuff not implemented yet (the comma key does not currently work properly) but it has a major flaw: **the UI is not updated when the keys `%` or `±` are pressed**.

I debugged the program and it appears that the calculator state (machine) *is* updated when those keys are pressed and the values are correct (e.g. the number is negated with `±`). Following this state update the view model `Published` property effectively triggers a `objectWillChange` emission, the `displayedValue` is computed, the `CalculatorView` body is called **but not the `ResultView` body**.

If my implementation is correct then it is not expected because the `result` property has changed, what is the cause of the issue?

Comment: In `ResultView`, the property cannot be let - let is not changed and will not trigger an update. Use @State instead - this is because SwiftUI uses State driven rendering, and even a normal var changing will not trigger the view to update.

Comment: `@State` is for UI-triggering properties own by the view, which is not the case here since `result` is passed by the parent view. A constant property is thus the right choice here.